# how to use a two word password on a script variable?

Tags: bash, scripting, backup, mysql

I'm trying to build a script to automate the backup process for an existing database.

The problem I'm having is passing to the `mysqldump` command (see bellow) the database password that has two words separated by a blank space.

```
# database credentials
DATABASEHOST="localhost"
DATABASEUSER="username"
DATABASEPASSWORD="Compound Password"
DATABASESCHEMA="schema"

# Local directory of mysqldump file
LOCALDIR=/home/user/db-bkp

#--- end config

mysqldump --host=$DATABASEHOST --user=$DATABASEUSER --password=$DATABASEPASSWORD $DATABASESCHEMA > $LOCALDIR/`date +%Y%m%d`_bkp_$DATABASESCHEMA.sql
```

When I run the script, the relevant `mysqldump` related message is:

`mysqldump: Got error: 1045: "Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" when trying to connect`

What am I doing wrong here and how to solve it?

Comment: See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quote your variables:

```
mysqldump --host="$DATABASEHOST" \
          --user="$DATABASEUSER" \
          --password="$DATABASEPASSWORD" \
          --database="$DATABASESCHEMA" \
  > "$LOCALDIR"/"$(date +%Y%m%d)_bkp_$DATABASESCHEMA.sql"
```

See also: [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)